# How to achieve Linux privilege escalation by polkitd without password but with Yes/No prompt?

Tags: linux, pam, polkit

I want to implement Window's UAC like access control using polkit(d). So if I open Network manager or printers, it should ask me yes/no. No password prompt but window must be showed to user.

I tried setting this in pam by setting the password to `ignore` I just hit `ok` and grant permissions without password.

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    optional  pam_permit.so
auth    required  pam_env.so
```

But there is still a password prompt.

Comment: What did you do? what  do you expect? What did you get?

Comment: I want UAC like dialog without password. Tryed echo, issue, etc..

Comment: Did you find a solution for this use case? I am also trying to do this on my laptop.

Comment: @TravisG. It heavily integrated to shell. I had no success.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own PAM module for that, both to produce the right question text and to correctly interpret the answer.

By manipulating the result codes of `pam_unix.so` you can make it so that any password is acceptable, and so you can just hit OK; *but will hitting Cancel then stop the action, or will it just happen anyway, no matter how the user answers?*

The important thing in UAC-like designs is that the prompts must happen *rarely enough* that the user will actually *stop and think*. If the prompts appear too often, it will just become a spinal reflex: "monkey see dialog, monkey click OK". If something requires you to enter a password "too often", it will probably be "too often" for UAC-like prompt, too.

Traditionally, Unix-like systems are generally assumed the user will mean what they say: the extra password prompts on sensitive things are primarily for ensuring that security sensitive commands are actually entered by the authorized user, not by a random passerby who has found an unlocked desktop session.

If what you are looking for is protection against your own "fingers-faster-than-brain" errors, that is a [molly-guard](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/molly-guard) ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/molly-guard), [Jargon File](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/molly-guard.html)), not a real security mechanism.

Comment: On other side many people work under root or enable sudo no-password feature or use password like 123 or write password on sticker on monotor. UAC-like dialog solved this problems. Even if it promted and not readed - it from system. I saying about polkit because it has polices what actions ask for password, what run without it.